# Вывод диалогового окна с голосованием при закрытии вкладки пользователем

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, css3

Можно ли как-то вывести вопрос с просьбой оценить качество сайта по шкале от 1 до 10, когда пользователь закрывает вкладку в браузере, и если оценка ниже 9 спросить в чем, по его мнению, проблема?
Это должно быть похоже на пример окна, когда просят подтвердить действительно ли вы намерены покинуть страницу. Либо вывод окна сформированного с помощью `CSS`.

Answer (score 1):

А если попробовать использовать window.onbeforeunload ??
Что-то вроде такого:

```
<script>
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
    e = e || window.event;

    // For IE and Firefox prior to version 4
    if (e) {
        e.returnValue = 'Sure?';
    }

    // For Safari
    return 'Sure?';
};
</script>
```

Скопировал отсюда: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser
Тут наверное надо будет использовать e.preventDefault()...

Comment: Принцип работы что надо, только возможно ли поместить туда голосование? т.е. `html` и `css` код

Comment: Добавляете в обработчик события генерацию и создание формы с голосованием.   
По ajax'у передаете ответ на сервер.   
Потом закрываете таб (с помощью window.close() кажется...)

Comment: `onbeforeunload` не может предотвратить закрытие окна, поэтому создание формы не получится

Comment: @Grundy Даааа.... Вы правы... :(

Comment: [справка по этому евенту](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: @Grundy закрытие не требуется предотвращать, основная задача показать голосование пользователю, который по каким-то причинам уходит с сайта и спросить почему он так решил сделать. То есть обратная связь, чтобы в дальнейшем я мог убрать эту проблему и не потерять клиента. Возможно реализовать?

Comment: @Plush, максимум можете вывести сообщение с предложением остаться на странице, прочитайте справку. Раньше можно было хотя бы `promt` или другие функции вставлять, а сейчас они могут даже не запускаться

Comment: @Plush В функции обработчика onbeforeunload вы можете открыть другое окно, в котором будет голосование. Мне кажется - это и будет решением вашей задачи.

Comment: @MichaelVaysman, каким образом?

Comment: Надо помнить только, что `onbeforeunload`  не во всех браузерах будет работать. Например в `opera` которая раньше 2013 года, которая не на вебките, а также, возможно в IE

Comment: @Grundy Ну например так:  window.open("http://mysite.com/queston");

Comment: @MichaelVaysman, пробовали этот вариант? :-)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, в последних версиях во всех, в IE кстати с 4 версии :-)

Comment: @Grundy Признаться, кидаю возможные варианты решения, пока по телефоны разговариваю :))

Comment: @MichaelVaysman, вот и я про то же :-)

Comment: @Grundy Мда... Firefox блокирует попытку открытия окна...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31636/discussion-between-grundy-and-michael-vaysman).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, должно работать.
В сниппете отправка формы блокируется защитой браузера, но на странице не должна.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  $("body").html($("#rate").show().submit(function () { setTimeout(function () { window.close() }) }));
  window.onbeforeunload = null;
  return "Пожалуйста, останьтесь на странице и оцените её.\nПосле оценки вкладка сама закроется."
};
```

```css
input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#rate {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Тут был какой-то контент.

<form id=rate>
  <input type=range min=0 max=10 value=0>
  <input type=submit value=Отправить>
</form>
```

Чтобы увидеть диалог, надо запустить сниппет ещё раз.

Comment: Да, это вариант. Можно внести свой текст в диалог окно "Эта страница просит вас подтвердить..."?